# Where are WMTS tiles stored/cached on QGIS Server?

Tags: qgis-server, wmts, cache

I am using QGIS server 3.30 to serve projects with WMTS. This seems to render the tiles as they are requested, similar to WMS. Are the tiles, when first requested, stored somewhere on the server PC for the next user to access? Can I access these files or prerender them?
I can find no details in the official documentation for QGIS server.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS by default has a tile cache enabled, you should find it in your profile directory under `/cache` with the size of 50 MB. As explained in the [official documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/server_manual/config.html#environment-variables), you can change location with parameter `QGIS_SERVER_CACHE_DIRECTORY` and size with parameter `QGIS_SERVER_CACHE_SIZE`.

I'm not aware of any script to prerender these tiles, it should be possible to write one using *PyQGIS* so. For now I would recommend you external tools like [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/).